# Issues with intermediary many to many field in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am inserting data in models which are related with other models via Many-to-Many relations. I was trying to use add() to add values in many-to-many filed but that doesn't work and raise this error `Cannot set values on a ManyToManyField which specifies an intermediary model.`

I read the docs and found out that we cannot use `set(), add(), create()` for intermediary model.

Here are my models :

```
class Venue(MPTTModel):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, verbose_name=_('organisation'))
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), null=True, blank=True)
    address = models.ForeignKey(Address, verbose_name=_('address'))
    org_users = models.ManyToManyField(PortalUser, through='OrgMapping', verbose_name=_('org users'))
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(_('modified at'), auto_now=True)

class OrgMapping(models.Model):
    host_group = models.ForeignKey(OrgHostGroups, verbose_name=_('host group'))
    org_user = models.ForeignKey(PortalUser, verbose_name=_('org user'))
    venue = models.ForeignKey(Venue, verbose_name=_('venue'))
    org_roles = models.ManyToManyField(OrgRole, verbose_name=_('org roles'))
    org_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(OrgPermission, verbose_name=_('org permissions'), blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(_('created at'), auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(_('modified at'), auto_now=True)
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(_('is deleted'), default=False)



def create_org_venue(org, name, desc, address, org_users):
    """
    org_users must be a list or portal users pk's
    """

    parent = get_or_none(Venue, organisation__name='TeraMatrix')
    venue = Venue(organisation=org,
                            name=name,
                            description='Head Office',
                            address=address)
    venue.save()
    # save org_users to above venue
    for user in org_users:
        # venue.org_users.add(user)
        venue.org_users = get_or_none(PortalUser,pk=user)
        venue.save()
    return venue
```

Now If I'll try to craete venue using `create_org_venue` it will raise error. Any idea how I can do this

**Edit :-**

```
class OrgHostGroups(MPTTModel):
    organisation = models.ForeignKey(Organisation, verbose_name=_('organisation'))
    name = models.CharField(_('name'), max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(_('description'), null=True, blank=True)
    org_users = models.ManyToManyField(PortalUser, through='OrgMapping', verbose_name=_('org users'))
    venues = models.ManyToManyField(Venue, through='OrgMapping', verbose_name=_('venues'))
```

As you can see Venue model mapped through orgmapping  and which further need orghostgroup and it needs venues and mapping again. So we can say that a circular relationship.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to use `add()` when using an intermediary model, because that wouldn't let you specify values for the extra fields on the intermediary model.

Instead, just create an instance of the intermediary model.

```
OrgMapping.objects.create(
    venue=venue,
    org_user=user,
    # set all the other required OrgMapping fields here
)
```

See the docs on [extra fields on many-to-many relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships) for more info.

Comment: Yes , I figure out that i need to crate instance of through mapping first. But my problem is little bit complex . I have edit my question can you please check

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand the problem. Can't you just call `OrgMapping.objects.create()` as many times as you want?